How to find a PC mouse exactly with my mouse design and size?
I have a very old mouse that I attach it photo here:



I need this PC mouse or a PC mouse that exactly like this mouse design.
my mouse size is about: 95×55×30
Is there any mouse for me? or anyone know this mouse model? or anyone know other mouse model that exactly like my mouse design and size?

But why exactly, tho? Your best bet is probably going to be to 3D print your own enclosure for an existing mouse. But, like, surely there's a mouse that's close enough to that that you can live with?

@JMY1000 "Exactly like this" mean a mouse that have exactly size like this and have very similar to this and have famous brand like a4tech or genius - need a mouse that very similar to this and have size 95×55×30

But why? There are lots of similar mice that aren’t exactly the same. Why does it need to be exactly the same?

@JMY1000 Because my hand is used to this size mouse

Surely there is something similarly sized that would be acceptable? If not, you should just keep using your current mouse.

@JMY1000 yes if there is something similarly sized it will be acceptable.
